# PHP simplexml and xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gallery>
    <album tnPath="tn/" lgPath="imm/" fsPath="iml/" >
        <img src="001.jpg" />
        <img src="002.jpg" />
    </album>
</gallery>
```

I am reading the file with:

```
$xmlFile = "xml.xml";
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlFile . "?" . time());
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
```

Now I am rebuilding the XML file and would like to save the **album** node with it's attributes in a var
I was thinking with xpath:

```
// these all return arrays with the images...
// echo $xmlObj->xpath('/gallery/album@tnPath');
// echo $xmlObj->xpath('//album[@tnPath]');
// echo $xmlObj->xpath('//@tnPath');
```

But that doesn't seem to work? Any help?

Comment: The `"?" . time()` stuff is not necessary. PHP has no cache when fetching remote ressources (assuming it is remote, otherwise it would be even more useless or even break opening the file)

Answer (score 0):

`$xmlObj->xpath('/gallery/album')` gives your the album node(s).

Comment: Ok, I got it working with $foo = $xmlObj->xpath('//@tnPath'); echo $foo[0];